# How to use junit5 with gradle 4.5

Tags: java, gradle, junit

For some reason I have to downgrade my gradle version from 4.10 to 4.5 in my project, but all of my test was written in junit5. It seems junit5 is not supported in gradle 4.5 because `useJUnitPlatform()` is introduced in gradle 4.6.

I wander is there some workaround to use junit5 with gardle4.5.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found gradle has provided a plugin to help write junit5 Test before 4.6 which is `junit-platform-gradle-plugin`.

Here is the main part of my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.2.0"
    }
}
allprojects {
    ...
    apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'
}
```